# Best way to setup auth on users behalf?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a website where the signup process is for authorised people only so site admins can only register user accounts.

I currently have this setup where I use signinwithemailandpassword provider and a form that just asks for display name, email and role (admin/client).

I generate random password in the signup function and use SendGrid to email it to the user so they can sign in.

Is there a more conventional  way to do this just using firebase as my SendGrid limit is almost at limit from testing and I’d rather keep the services in using to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this is to **not** preregister the users, but instead wait for them to sign up themselves. At that point you can then check (for example in [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions)) if the user is on an allow-list and either give them the correct role, or [reject their registration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#deploy_and_register_a_blocking_function) altogether.

You'll still need to send the users an invite for joining though, so this won't make a difference in the SendGrid quota you're using.

Comment: Thanks I actually really like this solution and it gets rid of the need for admins.